# Trigger bluetooth headphone connection system screen on Apple Watch

Tags: swift, swiftui, bluetooth, watchos

I'm working on an app for the Apple Watch and I'm looking to implement functionality similar to what I've observed in the Spotify app.

[image: Screenshot]

Specifically, I'm interested in triggering the screen that prompts the user to connect Bluetooth headphones if none are connected when attempting to play audio.

I have attached a screenshot from the Spotify app which shows the exact screen I'm referring to. This screen appears when I try to play music without any Bluetooth headphones connected.

Here's a snippet of code I've attempted in my SwiftUI app, which simply plays a sound through the Apple Watch speaker but doesn't trigger the Bluetooth headphone connection screen:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "demo", withExtension: "mp3")!)

    var body: some View {
        Button("Play Sound") {
            playSound()
        }
    }

    func playSound() {
        do {
            let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
            try audioSession.setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
            try audioSession.setActive(true)
            
            audioPlayer.play()
        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Could anyone guide me on how to invoke this screen?
Is there a specific API or system call that can bring up this screen on the Apple Watch?

Any pointers or code samples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable background audio support and set your audio session appropriately.

- Add "Background audio" to your watch app's capabilities
- Configure and activate the audio session for `.longform` playback

```
session.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback,
                        mode: .default,
                        policy: .longForm,
                        options: [])
```

- Activate the audio session:

```
session.activate(options: []) { (success, error) in
    // Check for an error and play audio.
}
```

If necessary, the system will display a route picker promoting the user to select a Bluetooth audio route.

For more information, refer to [this Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/storyboard_support/playing_background_audio)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to enable `Background Audio` from app capabilities.
then configure and activate a session.

Hope it will work. you can add the following code also.
[image: Enabling Background Audio Screenshot from Apple]

[Reference Code From Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/storyboard_support/playing_background_audio)

```
// Reference Code From Apple Developer Documentation
// Set up the session. 
let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
// Set up the session.
 let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
do {
try session.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback,
                        mode: .default,
                        policy: .longForm,
                        options: []) } catch let error {
fatalError("*** Unable to set up the audio session: \(error.localizedDescription) ***") }
// Set up the player.
 let player: AVAudioPlayer do {
player = try AVAudioPlayer(data: audioData) } catch let error {
print("*** Unable to set up the audio player: \(error.localizedDescription) ***")
// Handle the error here.
return 
}
// Activate and request the route.
 session.activate(options: []) { (success, error) in
guard error == nil else {
    print("*** An error occurred: \(error!.localizedDescription) ***")
    // Handle the error here.
    return
}
player.play() }
```